# StrawberryPerlのCPANを実行するとエラーが出る

Tags: windows, perl

Windows10 64ビット環境にStrawberryPerlをインストールしました。
この状態で、コマンドプロンプトを起動して、cpanコマンドを実行しようとしているんですが、下記のエラーが表示され、実行できません。

何か解決方法はありますでしょうか。以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

```
Can't locate CPAN/Author.pm in @INC (you may need to install the CPAN::Author module) (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl) at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/CPAN.pm line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/CPAN.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/App/Cpan.pm line 288.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/App/Cpan.pm line 288.
Compilation failed in require at /e/server/perl/perl/bin/cpan line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /e/server/perl/perl/bin/cpan line 7.
```

Comment: スタートメニューにCPAN Clientはありませんか？

Comment: 確かにスタートメニューから起動すれば動くようです。ですが、今回は事情があり、コマンドプロンプトで実行する必要があり、困っています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CPAN Client 自体がバッチファイルなので次のようにすれば実行できると思います。

`＜Strawberryインストール先＞\perl\bin\cpan.bat`

実行例

```
C:\>C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\cpan.bat
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Unable to get Terminal Size. The Win32 GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo call didn't wo
rk. The COLUMNS and LINES environment variables didn't work. at C:\Strawberry\pe
rl\vendor\lib/Term/ReadLine/readline.pm line 410.

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.27)
Enter 'h' for help.


cpan>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836862/strawberry-perl-cant-locate-app-cpan-pm)を参考にパス環境変数の順番を変更したところ、コマンドプロンプトで「cpan」だけで起動できるようになりました。